# Best practice for mail client

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, email

I am trying to build a mail client. It consists of 2 parts the server part the parses emails and stores them in SQL Server database and the client part which organizes the mails and creates new ones.

My concern is what is the best way to read emails in the client. I mean if I read them from database, I have a delay because the html data I have to read for all the messages an email has in a thread I think it creates a big traffic.

Should I download all locally, should I create a local database to sync with the master database or what else should it be a good practice? The code is in win forms vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be getting the latest email id and comparing it with what you've got (latest message) in you local db, it takes regular checks on server. If they're different then get emails which have come after the date of your last message in the db, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: so you suggest to create a local db

Comment: yes, that's what all mail clients are doing.(eg. Outlook) they all have local db to cache stuff.